# Customize AppInsights dashboard - show log query

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have an Office COM add-in and we want to capture telemetry using AppInsights. We're currently analyzing the feasibility.
The first item we've tried was to capture the host version.
Our prototype sends a JSON object to AppInsights. The JSON looks like

```
{
   "Office":{"Version":"365","Build":"13530.201011"}​}
}
```

and it is sent to AppInsights as a trace (one single call to telemetryClient.TrackTrace );

This way we'll be able to easily add more information as needed about the host application, for example whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.
Analyzing data is also simple, the following Kusto query easily extracts what we need:

```
traces
| extend environment=parse_json( message )
| extend officeVersion = tostring( environment.Office.Version )
| summarize cnt = cnt() by officeVersion
| project officeVersion, cnt
```

We want to pin this Kusto query to the AppInsights dashboard.
How can we do this?

Comment: did you try the "pin to dashboard" button on the logs page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the "pin to dashboard" button in the logs query screen. Note that you should run the query first, then the button will be enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, for your answer. I've tried that, but the button is disabled; its tooltip says "Pin to dashboard is not supported in this environment"

Comment: @Dan could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: and you shoud run the query first, then check that button.

Comment: Running the query has enabled the button. Please edit your answer to emphasize this step.

Comment: @Dan added it to answer.